# ui datepicker not working with minimum date

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I'm using angularjs and I am having a datepicker like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <div class="small-8 columns right-align">
      <input id="dateFrom"
          type="text"
          name="FromDate"
          class="text-right"
          date-model
          ui-date="{ dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd' }"
          ui-date-format="yy-mm-dd"
          ng-model="vm.FromDate"
          min="vm.testDate"
          required 
          />
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using both `min="vm.testDate"` and `min-date="vm.testDate"`. Both without any success. I can still choose all dates

```
vm.testDate = new Date();
```

Comment: Which datepicker you are using?

Comment: angular-ui-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the latest version ,it works,

```
 <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
        <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
 </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wh8y4not/)**

Comment: Will try..Will come back with status